# Infinite While Loop troubles

Tags: c++, methods, while-loop, do-while

I'm having some trouble with this while loop and was wondering if anyone could help. I'm trying to make a little display menu program that will read in a user input and make decisions based on the user's choice . I'm storing numbers the user enters into a vector for the calc methods I'll make later on. I get stuck in an infinite loop after selecting to print out the elements in the vector. I am also having trouble reading in user input again after entering a selection. For an example, I'll enter 'a' and it does nothing. I want the loop to keep iterating and displaying menu options until the user enter Q for quit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//Display function
void display_menu()
{
    cout<< "P - Print number\n"<<"A - Add a number to the list \n"<< "M - Display mean of numbers\n"
        << "S - Display smallest Number\n"<<"L - Display largest number\n"
        << "Q - Quit\n"<<"Please select an option\n";


}

//Decision structure depending on user choice
void user_choice()

{
    display_menu();

    vector<size_t> list{};

    char choice;

    cin>>choice;

    while(choice != 'Q' || choice != 'q'){
            //cout<<"enter another selection\n";

        if(choice == 'P' || choice == 'p')
        {
            if(list.empty())
            {
                cout<< "List is empty\n";
            }
            else
            {

                for(size_t i = 0; i<list.size(); i++)
                {
                    cout<< list[i];
                }
            }

            display_menu();
        }


        else if(choice == 'A' || choice == 'a')
        {
            cout<< "Enter a number to add to the list\n";
            for(size_t i = 0; i <= list.size(); i++)
            {
                //cin>>choice;
                list.push_back(choice);
            }

        }
    }

}
int main()
{
    //cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    user_choice();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(choice != 'Q' || choice != 'q')...` Think about that.

Comment: One of the ultimate debugging techniques s to apply divide and conquer to your code and remove code bit by bit while still having a program that compiles, runs, and fails the exact same way. Eventually you get down to a program that's 2-3 lines long, and at that point it's hard not to see the bug even if you can't see the solution. This can be slow going, but the vast majority of the time you'll spot the bug before you've removed half of the program.

Comment: @Beta Changing the || to an && is the correct way right?

Comment: Well, is something preventing you from changing `||` to `&&`, and seeing if it works?

Comment: @jjcode367 best way to check that boolean logic is good is by making a truth table. Something this small you can probably do in your head, but just to be sure, scribble it out on paper.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you read the user input outside the loop (`cin>>choice;`) so you read the user's preference, do some stuff, then display a menu but you then don't re-read the user's choice so the loop re-runs (you're in a `while` loop) with the same value for `choice`. Since you never re-read the choice it'll never change and your loop won't ever exit.

As @SamVarshavchik points out in his comments you have an additional issue that `choice != 'Q' || choice != 'q'` is always true - for example, if `choice=='Q'` then `choice != 'q'` is true so the `||` is true. So you'll have to fix that as well (changing the `||` to a `&&` or doing a `tolower` and checking only the lowercase or something similar should fix that).

Comment: Although that may be true as well, that is not the obvious reason for the infinite loop. Even if that part is done correctly, the infinite loop will remain infinite, because basic rules of logic dictate that the loop condition will never be false.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, that is also an issue. Updated my answer above.